# Can SPPersistedObject settings be updated by normal users if ran with elevated privileges?

Tags: 2010, 2013, development, security, runwithelevatedprivileges

I have a custom ribbon icon "Enlist" deployed to each document library. A normal (i.e. non-admin) user can click this icon; when he does, I would like to permanently save the document library information (ID, name) somewhere. A central admin can then (via a custom central admin page) see a list of all document libraries enlisted by users.

I'm thinking about using `SPPersistedObject` to store the document library information when a user clicks on the ribbon icon. However, afaik this requires farm admin privileges, which means that normal users will encounter an error when clicking "Enlist". **Would running the code that writes SPPersistedObject with elevated privileges resolve this problem**, or could an error still occur? This is what I mean:

```
// Execute this code when a ribbon icon is clicked by a normal user
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    // Write DocumentLibrary Id and Name to some custom SPPersistedObject
});
```

MSDN says that `RunWithElevatedPrivileges()` "runs under the Application Pool identity, which has site collection administrator privileges on all site collections hosted by that application pool." Is this enough to update `SPPersistedObject`?

Should I override `SPPersistedObject.HasAdditionalUpdateAccess` to always return true, or would this still not be enough for least-privileged environments? If not, what options do I have to store such information other than a custom database?

Comment: Are your document libraries all in the same site? in the same site collection? in different site collections?  Have you considered just saving this information to a SharePoint list instead of with SPPersistedObject? Is there something specific that is leading you towards an SPPersistedObject approach?

Comment: The document libraries are all across the farm - no limitations here, they can be in different site collections in different content databases in different web applications. The reason I'm not storing this in a list is that 1) supposedly, it's not a good idea if you're dealing with many items, e.g. 100k (perhaps this is more of a myth?) and 2) where would I store such a list to make it directly accessible via central admin? Wouldn't I still need to store its location somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Elevated privileges is not enough to write to the configuration
>   database. With elevated privileges you will use the the web
>   application app pool’s identitty, which has only read permission to
>   the config db by default. Of course admin user (which runs the central
>   admin should have read and write permissions).

See more at: http://joelblogs.co.uk/2010/10/10/persisting-configuration-data-in-sharepoint-2010-with-sppersistedobject/

```
SPPersistedObject.HasAdditionalUpdateAccess
```

still needs the non farm admin user to be impersonated to farm admin user.

> One final topic that requires some coverage is security. As described
>   earlier, the HOS exists in the farm configuration database. Strictly
>   speaking it exists to support administrative functionality however it
>   has uses beyond this scope. For example, if we’re building a custom
>   timer job and we want to have the ability to submit tasks to our job
>   for completion. It’s most likely that these tasks will originate
>   within a non-administrative scope. Possibly as the result of a user
>   clicking a button on a webpart on some other site collection. With
>   previous versions of SharePoint, this simply wasn’t possible. Only
>   farm administrators could update the HOS. However with SharePoint
>   2010, an addition has been made to the base SPPersistedObject that
>   opens up the HOS to other users. To see how this works, we can modify
>   our Main function as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace PersistedObjectDemo
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private const int LOGON_TYPE_INTERACTIVE = 2;
        private const int LOGON_TYPE_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool LogonUser(string userName, string domain, string password, int logonType,
                                            int logonProvider, ref IntPtr accessToken);

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                IntPtr accessToken = IntPtr.Zero;
                if (LogonUser("non-farm-admin-username", "your-domain-name", "your-password", LOGON_TYPE_INTERACTIVE,
                              LOGON_TYPE_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref accessToken))
                {
                    using (var identity = new WindowsIdentity(accessToken))
                    {
                        using (identity.Impersonate())
                        {
                            MyPersistedObject obj = MyPersistedObject.Local;
                   //delete existing object and recreate to keep things simple
                            obj.Delete();
                            obj = MyPersistedObject.Local;
                            obj.Foo = "Some updated value";
                            obj.Update();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press return to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

> This code simulates an attempt by a non-farm admin user to update the
>   HOS. If we run this we’ll see the following exception which is our
>   gotcha number 3:
>
> System.Security.SecurityException: Access denied. at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObject.BaseUpdate() at
>   PersistedObjectDemo.MyPersistedObject.Update()
>
> Unsurprisingly, trying to update the HOS using a non-farm admin user
>   throws an exception. However, if we add the following code to
>   MyPersistedObject.cs and run our program again, we can see that the
>   HOS is updated appropriately.

```
protected override bool HasAdditionalUpdateAccess()
{
    return true;
}
```

> Of course, in a real-world application, we’d probably want to add some
>   security checking in this function rather than simply returning true
>   and allowing anybody to update our object but hopefully this
>   illustrates the point sufficiently.
>
> There is one other gotcha with regard to security – when SharePoint is
>   2010 installed, by default only the farm admin account has read/write
>   access to the config database. In a least-privilege installation, all
>   web applications other then Central Administration, will be running
>   under their own service account and these accounts will not have write
>   access to the config database. Consequently, adding, deleting and
>   updating objects in the HOS will not be possible. Although overriding
>   HasAdditionalUpdateAccess allows us a bit more control over who can
>   update the HOS, if the underlying app pool account doesn’t have the
>   appropriate database permissions we’re going to come unstuck pretty
>   quickly.

- See more at: http://www.chaholl.com/archive/2011/01/30/the-skinny-on-sppersistedobject-and-the-hierarchical-object-store-in.aspx#sthash.YUJnw8Op.dpuf

Comment: nice answer, a very useful reminder

Comment: So to summarize, the general, least-assuming answer to the original question is "no". The way I see it, this means that `SPPersistedObjects` are useless for passing information farm-wide between normal and farm admin users. Are there any other built-in alternatives for this? There are e.g. site property bags, but there we have another problem: how to make a farm admin know which sites' property bags to check for stored values?

Comment: `SPPersitedObjects` are still the best there is for farm wide settings. web.config is pretty ugly, but so is giving RW access to your config DB for your webapp accounts...